# How to get the name of each sheets of excel using vb/ssis

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel, ssis, vba

In the ssis Excel Source Editor,the name of the excel sheet is available.
is there any way to get that name on to a variable?
or is there any way to get the name of each and every sheets in the xlsx file?
using vb or any other ssis method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I skip items in a foreach loop container set to foreach ado enumerator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311752/how-can-i-skip-items-in-a-foreach-loop-container-set-to-foreach-ado-enumerator)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
For i=0 to ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count-1
   msgbox(WorkSheets(i).Name)
Next
```

I don't know how you need the result. You may want to store it in an array.

Comment: i need to store this name into a target table

Answer (score 0):

This will work (insert code into a code module):

```
Sub IterateAllWorksheetNames()
    dim wksht as Worksheet, FriendlyNameStr as String, CodeNameStr As String

    For Each wksht in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        wkshtNameStr = wksht.Name '// This is your worksheet "friendly" name 
                                  '// (..the name that is on the worksheet tab).

        CodeNameStr = wksht.CodeName '// This is the CodeName of the worksheet
                                     '// (..the actual object name in the collection)
    Next wksht


    '//  NOTE: By Default the CodeName and FriendlyName are by default the same (sheet1,
    '//  sheet2..) so don't get confused. You're probably looking for just "wksht.Name"

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**:
Sorry, I didnt see that you wanted it in a table.. This will add a table to Sheet2. Make sure your workbook has a "Sheet2", or just insert any EMPTY worksheet name into the Sheets() method..

```
Dim wksht As Worksheet: Set wksht = Sheets("Sheet2")

With wksht.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange)
    .Name = "MyWorksheetNames"
    .ListColumns(1).Name = "FriendlyNames"
    .ListColumns.Add(2).Name = "CodeNames"

    For Each x In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With .ListRows.Add
            .Range(1, 1).Value = x.Name
            .Range(1, 2).Value = x.CodeName
        End With
    Next x
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in vb.net bind sheet name to Combobox

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load        Dim filePath As String = "C:\Book1.xlsx" 
Dim connString As String = String.Empty        
If filePath.EndsWith(".xlsx") Then            '2007 Format            
connString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No'", filePath)        
Else            '2003 Format            
connString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No'", filePath)        
End If         'Get the Sheets in Excel WorkBook        
Dim connExcel As New OleDbConnection(connString)        
Dim cmdExcel As New OleDbCommand()        
Dim oda As New OleDbDataAdapter()        
cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel        
connExcel.Open()        
cmbSheets.DataSource = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)        cmbSheets.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME"        cmbSheets.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME"        connExcel.Close()    
End Sub
```